# How to hide/encrypt password in Sensu configuration?

Tags: rabbitmq, password-encryption, sensu

I have following configuration to connect with RabbitMQ server. While configuring Sensu , rabbitmq password given in plain text. For security issue, I need to hide or encrypted this password. How can we do it?

File content : `/etc/sensu/rabbitmq.json`

```
{
   "rabbitmq": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5672,
    "vhost": "/sensu",
    "user": "sensu",
    "password": "**secret**"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to have encryption in-flight with TLS, you'll want to look into [enabling TLS listeners for RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

[Sensu's official documentation](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.1/reference/ssl.html#configuring-sensu--rabbitmq-for-ssl-encryption) also shows how to configure Sensu to communicate with a TLS-enabled RabbitMQ.

Comment: this isn't what OP asked for. RabbitMQ password is exposed in client through a configuration file regardless of TLS configuration.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks for your comment. Looking back at my answer, I have no idea what I was thinking.

Comment: @AshishG: The information APIs from Sensu should already redact the RabbitMQ password. If your concern is to hide/encrypt the plain-text password that is saved within the file on the filesystem, I don't think that is possible. Your best bet would be to limit the permissions of that file to only be readable by the user that runs the Sensu services.